# Floor color in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to specify the floor color in a gnuplot surface plot (`splot`)?

I know there's an option to project the surface colors on the floor but I'm looking for a way to colorize the base (space between the X/Y axis at the bottom) in some uniform color other than the background color, i.e. white.

[image: Current gnuplot output]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but here are two approximations:

***version 5.2 (current)***

```
set mxtics 20              # lots of mx tics
set mytics 20              # lots of my tics
set ticscale 1.0, 0.01     # deemphasize tic marks
set grid x y mx my lt 1 lc "gray" lw 2   # fat grid lines

splot x*y lc palette
```

[image]

***version 5.3 (development version)***

```
set zrange [-100:100]
set xyplane at -100
set border linewidth 2
set wall z0 fillstyle transparent solid 0.5 fillcolor "gray"
splot [0:10][0:10] x*y lc palette
```

[image]

The fill style is set to partial transparency so the tic marks show through.

Comment: That's pretty close, thanks a lot!   I suppose there's no way at this point keeping the tick marks on all axis? Looks like they're painted over by the solid plane.

Comment: In the version 5.3 `set wall` treatment you could also add `set grid front`. That would draw all tic marks and axis/border lines on top of the other plot elements, probably including your data.  It might look terrible or it might make the data look semi-transparent which would probably be OK.  Try it and see.

Comment: I missed an improved variant.  Make the floor itself partically transparent so the tic marks show through. This is actually the default but I forgot the reason for it.  I have edited the answer to show this.

Comment: That's what I was originally looking for - many thanks!   Looks like I should update to the current dev. version :-)

Comment: With gnuplot 5.4 now being available I've tried the new `wall` option and it works great -
any way to position the wall no the axis?

Comment: The `set wall` commands are a convenience wrapper for `set object <index> polygon from x1,y1,z1 to x2,y2,z2 to x3,y3,z3 to x4,y4,z4` where the coordinates have been pre-set to the vertices of the box enclosing the plot.  You can add a similar rectangular polygon at some other location by entering the full `set object` command.